# Cloudformation template update without deleting the existing stack and resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, devops, infrastructure-as-code, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I have created a stack with multiple resources such as s3 , dynamodb ,lambda functions.
I am trying to update the stack with the same environment, but the resources names of both the stacks are same such as "dynamodb_cust_data_dev" .

I always get an error that this xyz resource already exists with the same name.
Stack creation failed

> client_variable_mapping_dev already exists in stack arn:aws:cloudformation:ap-south-1:505xxxxxxx:stack/dev-test/f7f1af20-e199-11ec-b2be-061b20ab09f2

Is it possible that the new stack overwrites the old resources which have the same names?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible that the new stack overwrites the old resources which have the same names?

No. Your deployment will just fail. You must use different names, or just let CloudFormation generate random name for your resources.